# MongoDb docker hangs after some requests

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have MongoDB running in Docker for Windows on my local machine. The configuration from my compose file is:

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

At the moment i am building an import process with ASP.NET Core where I have to import about 1.1 Mio documents. I realized that the import process just stops after about 400k items. When I break the process I a task from the network layer (NetworkStream.WriteAsync) but no busy or waiting thread at all. MongoDB is still alive, I can connect with MongoChef and also run queries.

I import the document in batches of 5.000 items:

```
var requests = 
    this.transformedHotels.Select(x => 
        new ReplaceOneModel<MongoTransformedHotel>(Builders<MongoTransformedHotel>.Filter.Eq(y => y.Id, x.Id), x)
        {
            IsUpsert =  true
        });

return this.collection.BulkWriteAsync(requests);
```

When I run MongoDB without docker it works. What can cause my network connection to hang?

Comment: Have you checked if your docker-machine still has enough disk space? I guess your Mongo container will write some data into its container. Maybe it reaches the VM's limits.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, 25 GB of 60 GB used at the moment.